# What's wrong in my react redux application ,as it's not rendering things as expected?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

I started using redux and just to test things out i started using combineReducers for more structured approach of designing things out ,but it doesn't work the same as everyone suggested.I have been scratching my head out that what's wrong in my approach as i followed every points that's on their official website.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStore}  from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reducer from './reducer';
import Welcome from './Components/Welcome';

const store=createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    <Welcome/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Welcome.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FIRST} from '../Actions';
function Welcome({count,dispatch})   {
    dispatch({type:FIRST});
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Wow it's great {count}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps=(store) =>({
count:store.count
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Welcome);
```

loginsearch.js

```
import {FIRST} from './Actions';
const initialstore={
    count:1,
    total:1
}

function loginreducer(state=initialstore,action)
{
if(action.type === FIRST)
{ 
  return{...state,count:0};
}
return state;
}

export default loginreducer;
```

searchreducer.js

```
const initialstore={
item:1,
search:1
}


function searchreducer(state=initialstore,action)
{
    return state;
}
export default searchreducer;
```

reducer.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import  loginreducer from './loginreducer';
import searchreducer from './searchreducer';

export default combineReducers({
loginreducer,
searchreducer
})
```

and when i `console.log(count)` in Welcome.js after `dispatch({type:FIRST})`

i get undefined ,however in application i should get Wow it's great 0

[image: image of app]

Comment: Log the state or use redux devtools and you'll see what the state is.

Comment: I have logged the state before dispatch showing count 1 and total 1 after dispatch shows undefined for both. Do you find any error in this ?

Comment: @Mayanktiwari I don't see any property called `count` in your reducer combination. If you log `store` in `mapStateToProps` what do you see? A reproducible example of this would help as well

Comment: @Mayanktiwari log the state in your mapStateToProps or use the devtools. About 90% of redux questions on SO would not be here if people just checked the devtools.\

Comment: Ok I will use from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you combined the reducers, but when calling the state from mapStateToProps, you forgot to add which reducer you are actually referring, so you get undefined.

I added keys to your reducers, so it can be much easier to call outside. And updated the mapStateToProps

Here is the example to fix your issue,

```
/*reducer.js*/
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import  loginreducer from './loginreducer';
import searchreducer from './searchreducer';

export default combineReducers({
lr: loginreducer, // <== Check this line
sr: searchreducer // <== Check this line
})


/*welcome.js*/
const mapStateToProps=(store) =>({
count:store.lr.count, // <== Check this line
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Welcome);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,that's thing I was missing :))